# Trying to understand clock circuit (wall clock, not signaling clock)

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator, ripple-counter, frequency-divider

First of all, electronics is a new hobby for me.  I don't have any formal training, so please be patient with me.

Probably like many people, I picked up the interest after playing with Arduinos.  I have an IT background so programming an MCU came relatively easy (for the basics at least).  The more I get into it though, the more I want to understand how these things work at a more fundamental level.

I've been learning about basic concepts starting with the common components, and I've started to look at basic circuit concepts such as voltage dividers, power supplies (regulated, switching, etc), oscillators, and so on.

I've begun to look at reverse engineering basic applications (really just trying to figure out how I'd approach it or how other people have solved it).  That brought me to a typical analog wall clock.

There are a ton of videos and write-ups on how these things work, and I completely understand the gear and solenoid portion.  What I'm trying to understand is the actual solenoid trigger.  I ended up buying a cheap one from Walmart for $3 and some change.  After taking it apart though, there's a blob of epoxy or something covering what I believe is the key component(s).

I think I've hit a dead end trying to understand how I might re-create this circuit, but it seems like a crystal oscillator with a ripple counter might be along the right path??  What I get hung up on is that I paid $3.88 for the entire clock so I doubt its any sort of MCU, and I can't seem to track down any discrete components that get me anywhere close to the prices these things sell for (I'm sure economies of scale comes into play here though).  Also can't find components that'll work off of a single 1.5V AA battery.  Maybe the crystal/counter is the wrong direction?  (I understand that I could boost the voltage but it's unclear to me what that would do to the battery life).

Anyway, after all of that mostly superfluous info, here's my question:  Can anyone tell me what type of circuits/primitives I should be researching?  A schematic would be amazing, but really I'm just looking to get pointed in the right direction.  Even "look up this component..." or "search for these key words..." would be a big help.

Thanks!!

Comment: You're on the right track - crystal oscillator driving a ripple counter. There is a single chip that generates one-second pulses, but it does not contain the solenoid driver (look for variants of CD4060). It does the crystal oscillator + ripple counter part, but may require a bit more than 1.5V. It will be hard finding the chip used in watches (unless you want a million of them).

Comment: `I paid $3.88 for the entire clock so I doubt its any sort of MCU` ... you can get an MCU for just a couple of cents

Comment: @nw47978:  The "black blob" is most likely a pre programmed microprocessor.  It's under a black blob because the bare chip is cheaper than a packaged chip.  The company that builds the clocks mounts the bare chip, wires it, then "blobs" it.  If it works, fine.  If not, toss it in the scrap bin.  They build the things by the literal boat load, as cheaply as possible.  They use low quality parts and simply thow away any finished unit that doesn't work.

Comment: The simplest way to replicate such a thing is using any low power microprocessor you like.

Answer (score 2):

The driver in solenoid clock is a peculiar and almost unique circuit. As in, it's used only in clocks but there are a lot of these around!

The blob is a dedicated IC, you most probably see a tiny little metal can near it: that's a 32.768kHz crystal. 32768 is 2 to the 16 power so with a simple binary divider you can have a 1Hz signal. On each of these tick the ICs gives a little pulse to the solenoid and advances the clock (there are variants, some clocks go a 2Hz due to the mechanism, for example).

The trick in that circuit is that its consumption is in the microampere range, so a battery can drive it for years. I think it would be quite difficult to redo it as a discrete circuit and I don't know if such an IC is available in packaged form

To have an idea of how modern clocks could work read this http://blaauw.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/342/2017/11/YoonA558nWCrystalOscillatorUsingPulsed.pdf